# How to add elements using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add elements on click event, there is an input text element and when user clicks on add I want to add that as an item to an unordered list. This is simple I prefer to do it with just JS but have to use JQuery. So, basically I want to:

1. get value of the input text
2. append li item to ul list
3. append a label for the li item
4. add value from input as text for label.

Here's my code - it's definitely not working but the above 4 steps is what I want to achieved in JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $add_button = $('#add-item')
    var newItem;
    var $incompleteTasks = $('#incomplete-tasks');
    $add_button.click(function(){
        newItem = $('#new-task').val();
        // append new item to incomplete tasks ul
        $incompleteTasks.append('<li>appended</li>')
            .append('<label></label>').text(newItem);
    });
});
```

Comment: Some HTML would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this one:

```
$incompleteTasks
.append('<li>appended</li>')
.append('<label></label>')
.text(newItem);
```

You're using a [*chaining*](http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/quick-guide-chaining-in-jquery/). It means that every `.append(something)` returns `$incompleteTasks` element with updated content.
Calling `.text(newItem)` at the end, you're replacing whole content of the element by just single inputfield value:

```
$incompleteTasks
.append('<li>appended</li>')
//RESULT: <ul><li>appended</li></ul>

.append('<label></label>')
//RESULT: <ul><li>appended</li><label></label></ul>

.text(newItem);
//RESULT: <ul>newItem</ul>
```

If you want to append the value to the `<label>` and then that `<label>...</label>` to the `<ul>` element, you can do this way:

```
$incompleteTasks.append('<li><label>'+newItem+'</label></li>');
// OR:
$('<li><label>'+newItem+'</label></li>').appendTo($incompleteTasks);
// OR:
var label = $('<label/>').text(newItem);
$('<li />').append(label).appendTo($incompleteTasks);
// ...
```

You should end up with code like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $add_button = $('#add-item')
    var newItem;
    var $incompleteTasks = $('#incomplete-tasks');
    
    $add_button.click(function(){
        
        newItem = $('#new-task').val();
        // Create <label> element and append text in:
        var label = $('<label/>').text(newItem);
        // Create <li> element, append prevously created <label>, and finally append that <li> to <ul>:
        $('<li />').append(label).appendTo($incompleteTasks);
        
    });
});
```

```css
label{
 display:block;
 border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
 background:#fafafa;
 width:200px;
 padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=text id=new-task>
<button id=add-item>add-item</button>
<ul id=incomplete-tasks></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem in `.text(newItem)` because it is called on 
`$incompleteTasks` and every time overrides `ul`'s content.

Fix:

```
$incompleteTasks.append('<li>appended</li>').append('<label>'+newItem+'</label>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b4y8Lxf4/